# Mysql, remove row with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

[image]
<sub>(source: [visedeg.no](http://visedeg.no/images/4ewq24mr3r76uuhq9324.png))</sub>

On the picture you see i have rows with same value. I want to show them only one time.
The values in the row is a sum of every money in week 9.

```
<? 
$result5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Donering WHERE Uke=".$Uke."");

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result5)){
    $nick = $row1['nickid'];
    $result6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Donering WHERE nickid=".$nick." and Uke=".$Uke."  ");

    echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Brukernavn</th>
        <th>Kr</th>
        <th>Uke</th>
        </tr>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result6))  {
        $sum2 = $sum2+$row['Penger'];
        $DittNick = $row['Nick'];
    }

    if ($sum2 >= 2500000000) {
        $Fargekode = "#00FF00";
    }
    else {
        $Fargekode = "#FF0000";
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $DittNick . "</td>";
    echo "<td><font color='".$Fargekode."'>". number_format ($sum2 , 0, ',', '.'  ) . "   </font></td>";
    echo "<td>Uke ".$Uke."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";

    $sum2 = NULL;
}?>
```

Comment: Use `Group By` with your query

Comment: Of course :)
how could i be so stupid. 
Tnx !

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `mysql_*` is being deprecated. Look at the bottom of my answer for more information on that. If you don't, some day your code will be useless.

For you actual query, try using `SELECT DISTINCT`. This will pull unique rows.

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this, move the header of the table, and the close out of the while

```
<?$result5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Donering WHERE Uke=".$Uke."");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Brukernavn</th>
<th>Kr</th>
<th>Uke</th>
</tr>";

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result5)){
$nick = $row1['nickid'];

$result6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Donering WHERE nickid=".$nick." and Uke=".$Uke."  ");



while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result6))  {


$sum2 = $sum2+$row['Penger'];

$DittNick = $row['Nick'];


}

if ($sum2 >= 2500000000) {
$Fargekode = "#00FF00";
}
 else {
$Fargekode = "#FF0000";
}

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $DittNick . "</td>";
echo "<td><font color='".$Fargekode."'>". number_format ($sum2 , 0, ',', '.'  ) . "    </font></td>";
 echo "<td>Uke ".$Uke."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";



  $sum2 = NULL;

  }

  echo "</table>";?>
```

Comment: Tnx for fast replay.
But then this happend: http://visedeg.no/images/lewl5e0yk5ciw89jfif1.png

Comment: I misunderstand the question, but maybe this will help too (thats why I didnt deleted it)

Comment: Did you move the </table> out of the while?

Comment: That was the html? Do you mean CSS?

Comment: The html result of the php. Right click->show source in the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use DISTINCT option in your MySQL string